# How do I create a DesiredCapabilities that can find a Chrome or Firefox instance?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I have Firefox and Chrome browsers available on my hub. I can request one or the other successfully. I'd like to run most of my tests on whichever is available, but not both (this is for application UI regression testing, not browser support testing, so I'd prefer to finish the tests fast for a smaller feedback loop). However when I remove the BrowserName capability from my `DesiredCapabilities` like this:

```
IWebDriver GetNewBrowser() {
    var capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities {
        Platform = new Platform(PlatformType.Windows)
    };
    return new RemoteWebDriver(hubUri, capabilities);
}
```

Then the Selenium Hub throws this wobbly:

```
System.InvalidOperationException : The best matching driver provider
     org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver can't create a new
     driver instance for Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS}]
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09
```

I don't want the best matching driver provider. I want *any* matching driver provider. How do I set this up?

Answer (score 1):

A custom `CapabilityMatcher` installed on the Grid might be the answer, see [this example](https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2014/01/19/working-with-a-custom-capability-matcher-in-the-grid/) (Java).

You could either override [DefaultCapabilityMatcher](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/server/src/org/openqa/grid/internal/utils/DefaultCapabilityMatcher.java) and patch the method to allow a requested `browserName` property to match anything (the default behaviour being to require an exact match) - or just rewrite the matching logic to your precise needs.

Comment: Thanks that code is helpful. It looks like it should match anything if the browserName capabilities is null, the empty string, `"` or `ANY`. I'm sort-of seeing that inasmuch as it finds the node, but then it goes on to require that the browser is IE. I wonder if there's another step that decides which browser to select after determining that the node matches the capabilities...

Comment: I guess that mechanism's not sophisticated enough to allow overriding of the browser name, and since you're not setting one, IE is nonetheless considered to be the default/fallback browser for the platform. Let me have a think...

Comment: Looks like I need a new custom DriverProvider registered with the hub. Or maybe [this driver provider project](https://github.com/betgenius/selenium-driver-provider) can help me. I'll check it out on Monday.

Comment: OK, yes, sounds like the could be the solution.

Comment: Alternatively I could add a CapabilitiesComparator that returns a random matching provider. That is supported by the existing capabilities. But it's not very satisfactory. I think I'll take this opportunity to add to the Selenium code base :)